# Canvas doesn't update after drawing images

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

I am designing a game in Java. I'm using a bit of code I found at [java-gaming.org](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=21919.0), and it seems to be working strangely.

When I run the loop as given, it will update my canvas correctly. However, I don't want it to always be updating my "background" so to speak. To fix this I had it only run once. Now it appears to run, but does not display the image I painted.

I've uploaded screenshots of the program running once (broken) and the program running continuously (working). See them on [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVH24.jpg).

*tldr;* Everything appears to run, but it doesn't display anything in my frame. see code below.

```
package main;

//imports...
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameEngine implements Runnable {
    //declare variables...
    final static int B_HEIGHT = 20;
    final static int B_WIDTH = 20;
    private int cellWidth = GameTester.WIDTH / B_WIDTH;
    private int cellHeight = GameTester.HEIGHT / B_HEIGHT;
    protected boolean init = true;
    JFrame frame;
    Canvas canvas;
    BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    Board gameBoard;
    Generator gen;

    long desiredFPS = 60;
    long desiredDeltaLoop = (1000 * 1000 * 1000) / desiredFPS;
    boolean running = true;

    public GameEngine(int width, int height) {

        //create the gamespace...
        gameBoard = new Board(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT);
        gen = new Generator();

        gen.addWalls(gameBoard);
        agents.Champion champ = new agents.Champion();
        items.Item item = new items.Item();
        gameBoard.placeChampion(champ);
        gameBoard.placeItem(item);

        //frame magic...
        frame = new JFrame("Basic Game");

        JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.setLayout(null);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        panel.add(canvas);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();

        canvas.requestFocus();
    }

    //actual game mechanics...
    public void run() {

        long beginLoopTime;
        long endLoopTime;
        long currentUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        long lastUpdateTime;
        long deltaLoop;

        //game loop...
        while (running) {
            beginLoopTime = System.nanoTime();


            //this draws things
            render();


            lastUpdateTime = currentUpdateTime;
            currentUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();

            //update magic...
            update((int) ((currentUpdateTime - lastUpdateTime) / (1000 * 1000)));

            endLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaLoop = endLoopTime - beginLoopTime;

            if (deltaLoop <= desiredDeltaLoop) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((desiredDeltaLoop - deltaLoop) / (1000 * 1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //creates g object...
    private void render() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, GameTester.WIDTH, GameTester.HEIGHT);
        render(g);
        g.dispose();
        bufferStrategy.show();
    }

    // does nothing important...
    private double x = 0;
    protected void update(int deltaTime) {
        if (GameTester.dbglvl > 1) {
            System.out.println("update called");
        }
        x += deltaTime * 0.2;
        while (x > 500) {
            x -= 500;
        }
    }

    // ACTUAL GAME DRAWING MECHANISM...
    protected void render(Graphics2D g) {
        //first run
        if (init) {
            renderinit(g);
        } else {
            //every other time after first run
        }
    }

    //first run (generates game board)
    protected void renderinit(Graphics2D g) {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        //loop through 2d array
        for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.getWidth(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < gameBoard.getHeight(); col++) {
                //get image path
                String str = gameBoard.getSpace(row, col).getPath();

                //debug info
                if (GameTester.dbglvl > 1) {
                    System.out.println(gameBoard.getSpace(row, col).getPath());
                }

                //get the image to be rendered
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new File(str));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (GameTester.dbglvl > 0) {
                        System.out
                                .println("image get failed - image specified: "
                                        + str + " ");
                    }
                }

                if (GameTester.dbglvl > 1) {
                    System.out.println("Image Destination: (" + row * cellWidth
                            + ", " + col * cellHeight + ")");
                }

                //draws given image
                g.drawImage(img, row * cellWidth, // DX1
                        col * cellHeight, // DY1
                        (row * cellWidth) + cellWidth, // DX2
                        (col * cellHeight) + cellHeight, // DY2
                        0, // SX1
                        0, // SY1
                        img.getWidth(), // SX2
                        img.getHeight(), // SY2
                        null);

            }
        }
        //done with first time run
        init = false;
        if (GameTester.dbglvl > 0) {
            System.out.println("Board Rendered");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Painting is destructive, that is, each time you're asked to "render" you MUST start from scratch and rebuild the entire state.  This is even more important when using a `BufferStrategy`, as it's using a page flipping technique, which means the `Graphics` context you might get from one render to another is likely to be different from the previous or next render cycle.  Where possible, anything that doesn't change (much) should be pre-rendered to a `BufferedImage` and only changed when and if needed.  This image should then be painted on each render cycle. It's simply faster that way...

Comment: I see. That makes a lot more sense! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, when ever `render` is called, it's calling `g.clearRect(0, 0, GameTester.WIDTH, GameTester.HEIGHT);` which is doing exactly as the method name suggests, clearing the `Graphics` context, although I'd use the size of the `Canvas` itself, but that's just me...

Comment: Try and think of it as a frame in a film.  Each frame is independent on the last or next